# Return 404 in MongoDB block

Tags: node.js, mongodb, koa

I use follow codes to insert something into mongodb, and if it is successfully insertted, I should get string with information `success`

```
if (email) {
    MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        const dbo = db.db("email");
        const dbObj = {email: email};
        dbo.collection("email").insertOne(dbObj, function(err, res) {
            if (err) throw err;
            ctx.body = "success";
            db.close();
        });
     });
} else {
   ctx.body = "email is missing";
}
```

And now the document can be inserted into mongodb, but the get `404 Not Found`, any ideas?

Comment: If the `email` is empty, I can get the `email is missing`.

Comment: you get 404 when to try to fetch it after adding?

Comment: @ShivamSood no, I thought when the document was added, the code will run here `ctx.body = "success";`  that means I will get `success`, but I get 404.

Comment: can u `console.log(err)` to see whats the error and which line is throwing it. Try it on both first and after Inserting

Comment: @ShivamSood seems the `callback` causes `ctx` doesn't work

Comment: can u post the error stack